# Rename OpenAPI's reference generated swagger.json

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation, openapi, nswag

I'd like to know how to rename generated swagger.json

[image]

when I add an OpenAPI service reference to my project in Visual studio 2019 via "Add new OpenAPI service reference" option.

[image]

I assume it should be something like it's done with a "ClassName".

```
<ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="OpenAPIs\swagger.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Namespace="PetStore.Client">
      <SourceUri>https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json</SourceUri>
      <ClassName>PetStoreClient</ClassName>
      <OutputPath>PetStoreClient.cs</OutputPath>
      <Options>/GenerateClientInterfaces:true /ClientBaseClass:ClientBase</Options>
    </OpenApiReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change this just change the `Include` parameter of `<OpenApiReference />` to another path. Then refresh the service reference.

[image: refresh button]

This might require cleaning the solution manually (for some reason OpenApi related things in `bin` and `obj` don't clean themselves sometimes).